# prove $\sqrt{a_n b_n}$ and $\frac{1}{2}(a_n+b_n)$ have same limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, recurrence-relations, proof-writing, problem-solving

I am given this problem:
let $a\ge0$,$b\ge0$, and the sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$ are defined in this way: $a_0:=a$, $b_0:=b$ and $a_{n+1}:= \sqrt{a_nb_n}$ and $b_{n+1}:=\frac{1}{2}(a_n+b_n)$ for all $n\in\Bbb{N}$

To prove is that both sequences converge and that they have the same limit. I don't know how to show this. I have spent 2 hours on this, no sign of success

Comment: A cute question (+1)

Comment: @Chris'ssister, thanks :)

Comment: For a generalization to $3$ sequences (adding harmonic inequality to the mix) see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2638101/how-can-we-show-that-a-n-b-n-c-n-are-convergent-and-have-the-same-li).

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The easy way to proceed, is to show that $a_n, b_n \geq 0$, and then $ b_{n+1} - a_{n+1} = \frac {1}{2} (\sqrt{b_{n}} -\sqrt{ a_{n}})^2$, so $ b_{n} \geq a_{n} \forall n \geq 2$.
Then, $a_{n+1} = \sqrt{a_n b_n} \geq a_n$ is an monotonically increasing sequence (after $n=2$).
$b_{n+1} = \frac {1}{2} (a_n + b_n) \leq b_n$ is a monotomically decreasing sequnece (after $n=2$).
Finally, $$ b_{n+1} - a_{n+1} = \frac {1}{2} (\sqrt{b_{n}} -\sqrt{ a_{n}})^2 \leq \frac {1}{2} (\sqrt{b_n} - \sqrt{a_n} ) ( \sqrt{b_n} + \sqrt{a_n} ) = \frac {1}{2} ( b_n - a_n) \leq \frac {1}{2^n} (b_1-a_1),$$ so the difference between the sequences go to 0. Hence, these sequences converge to the same limit.

---

Note: Of course we could show that since $a_i \leq b_2$, the limit of $a_i$ exists (since monotonic+bounded). But I think it's more fun to jump directly to the conclusion with the final step.

Comment: how do you know that $b_{n}$ is bounded? is it because it's a monotomically decreasing and greater than $0$ for every $n$?

Comment: and for $a_{n}$ is it formal to say that it's bounded by $b_{n}$ which is a monotomically decreasing and bounded by $0$?

Comment: @Jneven 1) I do not use that they are bounded. I have a monotonically increasing sequence $a_n$ and a monotonically decreasing sequence $b_n$ such that $b_n-a_n$ tends to 0. You should be able to conclude that these sequences converge to the same limit (Yes, I skipped a step, but this should be obvious).

Comment: 2) (I'm not certain if you're stating all of the information of the sequence, or relying on the problem) If that's all you have, then no. E.g. The sequnce $0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, ...$ is bounded the monotonically decreasing sequence $2,2,2,2, ...$ and by 0, but doesn't converge. In this case,we have $a_n$ is monotonic, so yes it convergs.

Comment: For the record, someone asked a question on this answer : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/927192/prove-that-sqrta-n-b-n-and-frac12a-nb-n-have-the-same-limit

Comment: @Jneven How $b_n - a_n$ tends to $0 ?$ As you said $b_n$ is decreasing sequence and $a_n$ is increasing sequence. So $b_n -a_n$ should tends to some negative number. Why zero? Please tell me....

Comment: @LuckyChouhan Because of that inequality $ (b_{n+1} - a_{n+1}) \leq 1/2^{\color{red} n } ( b_1 - a_1)$.  Note that $ b_n \geq a_n$, so $ b_n - a_n$ is positive and converges to a non-negative number (if it converges).

Comment: @CalvinLin Thank you for making it crystal clear.

Comment: How can you know that you can take the square roots? For your first line? In particular, how can u know $a_n, b_n \ge 0$? @CalvinLin

Comment: @user129393192 Added that in as a first step.

Comment: Ah, so it is necessary. How would you recommend doing that? @CalvinLin . Induct on both simultaneously?

Comment: @user129393192 Yup.

Answer (score 12):

This is not an answer. Just a long comment which gives a classical formula of Gauss for this common limit.

Let $a$, $b$ be real numbers with $a<b$. We define their arithmetic-geometric mean  $M(a,b)$ using the sequences  $a_n$, $b_n$ defined as follows:
  $a_0=a$, $b_0=b$ and inductively

$$ a_{n+1}={ a_n +b_n \over 2},     \qquad b_{n+1}=\sqrt {a_n b_n
}\ . $$

The two sequences converge to a unigue common limit  $M(a,b)$.
 Gauss discovered a beautiful formula for  $M(a,b)$  which can be
expressed as an elliptic integral

$$ { 1 \over  M(a,b)} = { 2 \over \pi} \int_0^{ { \pi \over 2}} {
d \theta \over \sqrt{ a^2 \cos^2 \theta + b^2 \sin^2 \theta}} \ .
$$

Comment: assuming the use of integrals isn't relevant for me (this question was introduced to me in the class of "calculus 1" where integrals are not in the syllabus) how would you bound $b_{n}$?

Comment: Another formula can be found here : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2301340/show-that-lim-n-to-inftyb-n-frac-sqrtb2-a2-arccos-fracab

Answer (score 9):

If $a_n\to l$ and $b_n \to s$ then from $b_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}(a_n+b_n)$ we get $s=\frac{1}{2}(l+s)\cdots$
To prove that they converge use [arithmetic and geometric mean inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means#The_inequality) to show (that $a_n\leq b_n$ so ...) they are monotonic ($a_n$ is increasing and $b_n$ decreasing). From $a_n\leq b_n$ conclude they are bounded.

Comment: Pambos, thanks, now i got it

Answer (score 1):

Relating to PAD's answer.

If
$I(a, b)
=\int_0^{\pi/2} \dfrac{dt}{\sqrt{a^2\cos^2t+b^2\sin^2t}}
$,
using Landen's transformation
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landen%27s_transformation)
you can show that
$I(a, b)
=I(\dfrac{a+b}{2}, \sqrt{ab})
$.

Using the well-known inequalities
in Calvin Lin's answer,
this shows that
$I(a, b)
=I(AGM(a, b), AGM(a, b))
=\dfrac{\pi}{2AGM(a, b)}
$,
which gives a quickly converging
way of computing
the complete elliptic integral
of the first kind.