# slightly different from AGM

Tags: limits, recurrence-relations

$a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n+b_n}{2}$

$b_{n+1}=\sqrt{a_{n+1}b_{n}}$

also, $a_1=a$ and  $b_1=b$

evaluate 
 $$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n}$$ 
This question is from guillaume musso's novel La Jeune Fille et la Nuit . I remember that the answer included $\arccos$ thing..I asked this question few days ago but didn't get satisfactory answer. Please help me.

Comment: Is this correct $b_{n+1}=\sqrt{a_{n+1}b_{n}}$? Or is it $b_{n+1}=\sqrt{a_{n}b_{n}}$

Comment: @MariaMazur I said it's different from agm because of that. So I'm confused.

Comment: assume $0 < a < b$, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2301340/59379) (note: $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} = 1$).

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Assuming that $a < b$, find $c$ and $\theta$ such that

$$ \frac{1}{\tan\theta} = \frac{a}{c}, \qquad \frac{1}{\sin\theta} = \frac{b}{c}. $$

Then the solution of the sequence is given by

$$ a_n = \frac{c}{2^{n-1}\tan(\theta/2^{n-1})}, \qquad b_n = \frac{c}{2^{n-1}\sin(\theta/2^{n-1})}, $$

and hence the common limit is given by $c/\theta$. This sequence can be traced back to Archimedes' algorithm to approximating the circumference of a circle by inscribed and circumscribed polygons, see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximations_of_%CF%80#Polygon_approximation_to_a_circle).