# Le=t $0<a_1<b_1$ For $n\geq 1$, define $a_{n+1}=\sqrt{a_n b_n}$ and $b_{n-1}=\frac{a_n+b_n}{2}.$ Then

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, telescopic-series

Let $0<a_1<b_1$ For $n\geq 1$, define $$a_{n+1}=\sqrt{a_n b_n}$$ and $$b_{n-1}=\frac{a_n+b_n}{2}.$$ Then which of the following is **NOT TRUE**?

(A) Both $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ converges, but the limits are not equal

(B) Both $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ converges, but the limits are equal

(C) $\{b_n\}$ is a decreasing sequence

(D) $\{a_n\}$ is an increasing sequence

**My try**
$b_n-b_{n-1}=\frac{a_{n+1}+b_{n+1}}{2}-\frac{a_n+b_n}{2}=\frac{a_{n+1}-a_{n}}{2}+\frac{b_{n+1}-b_n}{2}$

From this, we get  $\frac{a_{n+1}-a_{n}}{2}=b_n-b_{n-1}-\frac{b_{n+1}-b_n}{2}$

Using AM-GM inequality,
   $$a_{n+1}\leq b_{n-1}$$

$$a_3<b_1$$
$$a_4<b_2$$
$$a_5<b_3$$
$$a_6<b_4$$
$$...$$

I am not able to judge anything. Please help me.

Comment: You should be able to answer your question by reading this: [prove $\sqrt{a_n b_n}$ and $\frac{1}{2}(a_n+b_n)$ have same limit](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/267489/prove-sqrta-n-b-n-and-frac12a-nb-n-have-same-limit) (assuming you mean $b_{n\color{red}{+}1} = \frac{a_n + b_n}{2}$).

Comment: How to check the monotonicity?

Comment: Monotonicity is also mentioned in the above link.

Comment: Yes, Yes. Sorry...